# Не получается выложить API на HEROKU

Tags: node.js, git, api, хостинг, heroku

Я делаю API по книге. Дошёл до момента, когда выкладываем API на heroku. Всё шло по как надо до момента написания `$ git push heroku main`(я поменял branch с master на main, пока пытался найти проблему). Мне выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
Enumerating objects: 13639, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13639/13639), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9951/9951), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13639/13639), 12.70 MiB | 4.61 MiB/s, done.
Total 13639 (delta 2963), reused 13637 (delta 2962), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://git.heroku.com/matvey-note.git
remote:  !     error fetching custom buildpack https://git.heroku.com/matvey-note.git
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to matvey-note.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/matvey-note.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/matvey-note.git'
```

Последняя строка и `[remote rejected]` выделены красным цветом.

Я уже не знаю, что и думать. Единственная мысль, что может не нравиться heroku так это то, что папка `node_modules` и файл `package.json` находятся во внешней папке.

Comment: Я делал всё по инструкции в книге и на официальном сайте. Всё равно ошибка не пропала.

Данные команды я тоже прописывал
`$ heroku git:remote -a <YOUR_APP_NAME>`
`$ git add .`
`$ git commit -am "application ready for production"`